# Dynamically Named range in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy named range in excel from one sheet to another, this works superb when I am using a static name. However now I would like to get the named range from a userform list box, and I am unsure how to do this. My copy function takes in the row number and I need to find this row number based on the string coming from the Listbox. If the listbox says Bolts the named range would be _OutputBolts which is refered to A123.

```
    Call copyRows(ws, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Templates").[_DrawingInputs].Row)
    Call copyRows(ws, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Templates").[_GeneralInputs].Row)
    Call copyRows(ws, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Templates").[_MaterialData].Row)

If GUI.ListBox_AdditionalComponents.ListCount > 0 Then
        For i = 0 To GUI.ListBox_AdditionalComponents.ListCount - 1
            namedRange = "[_Output" & GUI.ListBox_AdditionalComponents.List(i) & "]"
            Call copyRows(ws, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Templates").namedRange.Row)
        Next i
    End If
```

The copy procedure

```
Public Sub copyRows(ByRef shNew As Worksheet, startRow As Integer)
    Dim i, j As Integer
    Dim wsTemplates As Worksheet
    Dim temp As Variant
    Dim rowOverview As Integer
    Dim lastCol As Integer

    On Error Resume Next

    Set wsTemplates = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Templates")


    i = startRow ' Where to copy from in templates

    j = getLastRow(shNew, 1) 'Where to copy to, i.e append
    If j > 2 Then
        j = j + 2
    End If


    Do While wsTemplates.Cells(i, 1) <> ""
        'copy the old range
        wsTemplates.Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy
        'paste it
        shNew.Rows(j).EntireRow.Select
        shNew.Paste

        'format height
        temp = wsTemplates.Rows(i).Height
        shNew.Rows(j).RowHeight = CInt(temp)


        ' fill in the value from the GUI
        temp = ""
        temp = GUI.Controls("TextBox_" & Replace(shNew.Cells(j, 1).value, " ", "")).value

        If temp = "" Then
            temp = GUI.Controls("ComboBox_" & Replace(shNew.Cells(j, 1).value, " ", "")).value
        End If


        If temp <> "" Then
            shNew.Cells(j, 4).value = temp
        End If

        'hyperlink drawing
        If shNew.Cells(j, 1).value = "Drawing Name" Then
           Call createHyperLink(shNew, j, 4, shNew.Cells(j, 4).value, GetFileNameWithOutExtension(getFilenameFromPath(shNew.Cells(j, 4).value)), shNew.Cells(j, 4).value)
        End If

        'update counters
        i = i + 1
        j = j + 1
    Loop


    ' Format column widths, seems to be bug in this one...Maybe move out due to the fact we could do this once..
    lastCol = getLastColumn(wsTemplates, 1)

    For i = 1 To lastCol
        temp = wsTemplates.Cells(1, i).Width
        shNew.Columns(i).ColumnWidth = temp
    Next i

End Sub
```

---

Solved by using Range(address), see comment

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Templates").namedRange.Row` ==> `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Templates").Range(namedRange).Row`

Comment: Please show how "this works superb when you are using a static name". Because from knowing this we can take it to an dynamic name then.

Comment: Also skatun, you may want to add a `DoEvents` before `Next i` so that you give the code ample amount of time to complete the `copyRows` operation before moving on to the next item...

Comment: @Siddharth Rout: Sure the square brackets should be around the named range's name?

Comment: @AxelRichter: No they won't be. I missed that :). Skatun, also change the line `namedRange = "[_Output" & GUI.ListBox_AdditionalComponents.List(i) & "]"` to `namedRange = "_Output" & GUI.ListBox_AdditionalComponents.List(i)`

Comment: @AxelRichter I have updated it now according to your input

Comment: @SiddharthRout or @ skatun, please post an answer of its own, as comments are ephemeral, thank you.